# `where` taking `true` or `false`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a 'match.com' style app for local dog adoptions, where a user or a dog can create a profile. In each profile, there are boolean fields. I want to display the correct dog that has the same `true` value in the dog profile with the corresponding boolean field in the user profile. In the example, if `Dog.kids_under_10` and `User.profile.kids_under_10` match, the dog is displayed. I can accomplish this with a `String` or `Integer` (`1` or `0`), but I am trying to learn the best way to write code.

I will eventually be passing additional params, but I think once I understand how to make the below example functional, I should be able to simply add params as needed using the same logic.

Controller:

```
@user = current_user.profile
@dogs = Dog.by_profile(params[@user.kids_under_10])
```

Model:

```
def self.by_profile(user_profile)
  Dog.where('kids_under_10 = ?', user_profile )
end
```

Comment: I can see that you like dogs. So do I. Wish your project succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@dogs` assignment can look like this

```
@dogs = Dog.where(kids_under_10: @user.kids_under_10)
```

There is no need for your `by_profile` class method.

---

If you want to keep the class method, your controller would look like this

```
@user = current_user.profile
@dogs = Dog.by_profile(@user)
```

and your model's class method, like this

```
def self.by_profile(user_profile)
  return [] if user_profile.nil?
  Dog.where(kids_under_10: user_profile.kids_under_10)
end
```

Comment: I was able to get that to work, however I have various other parameters that I will need to pass through and I am trying to stick to the "fat model/skinny controller" mantra.  Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I responded to the context given. Within the context provided, there's no need for that class method. If you want to keep that class method, change `user_profile` to `user_profile.kids_under_10` in the `where()` condition.

Comment: Since I already declared .kids_under_10 in the params, I don't understand why I need to add it again.  I tried your solution with the additional .kids_under_10 and it returns no dogs.  I replaced the variable with both a hard coded true and false, just to ensure it would display a dog in either instance, and it does.  It appears that when passing through the variable, it doesn't pass a true or false, but just ''.  I also verified via the rails console that the field was in fact a boolean, which it is.

Comment: implemented your suggestion.. received this error undefined method `kids_under_10' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means `current_user` has no associated `profile`. `current_user.profile` is evaluating to `nil`.

Comment: I added a case for when this happens; `[]` will return. Fixing the association is outside of the scope of this question though.

Comment: That sheds some light on the problem...  I'm guessing this is an issue with the TrueClass/FalseClass/NilClass.  I will continue to research this and repost when I have additonal info.  Thank you for your assistance!